# Connect to Embedded MySQL from Delphi XE3

Tags: mysql, delphi, embed, delphi-xe3

How could I connect to Embedded MySQL server (libmysqld.dll library) from Delphi XE3? For now I know only one way – use DevArt MyDAC components (specific TMyEmbConnection), but it is paid what is unacceptable for my task now. Try to use dbExpress, but not successful.

So, I have two questions: 
1. Can I use dbExpress or any other components from Delphi XE3? 
2. Any third-party components (prefer free)?

Thanks

Comment: is this a private project or did you plan to publish it?

Comment: then dont worry about MyDAC, because if you use the libmysql.dll you have to buy a license from mysql in most cases. Using MyDAC you dont have to, because you dont have to use the dll ;o)

Answer (score 1):

I've used [ZeosLib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zeoslib/) for that in the past.
Worked quite well actually, although really soon it turned out that it was easier to have a central database.

Several people wanted to use the application, and then they wanted to share their changes, and keep things in sync, etc.  Luckily, switching to a mysql server was not much more work than copying the data, and changing the connection component parameters.